# Icefaces: Bulk File upload?

Tags: file-upload, icefaces

I have a question regarding bulk uploading with icefaces. Currently I can upload one file at a time, ice:inputFile, but from a user point of view this isn't of much use.

Is it possible to upload multiple files at one time?

Over just upload all files in a given directory?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible to do multiple file upload with icefaces.
The upload component is 'really' stable since the 1.8.2 version, previous versions have a lot of bugs.

fyi, here is a nice solution to do multiple file upload using standard api.

http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/12/multiple-file-input-in-firefox-3-6/

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Try checking out:
swfUpload

It seems quite nice and is exactly what I needed.